# Special characters are not properly round-tripped when using the Wikipedia API

Tags: .net, vb.net, encoding, wikipedia-api

I'm messing with the Wikipedia API trying to find the English page from a Dutch one.
I get this in XML format but when I want to update the MySQL database special characters getting converted so the link becomes invalid.

**For example:**

The API returns this: Möhrenbach

When I save it, it becomes this: MÃ¶hrenbach

**Another Example**

The API returns this: Sarandi, Paraná

When I save it, it becomes this: Sarandi, ParanÃ¡

**The Code I Use**

```
'SourceString is the XML response from Wikipedia Api
Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument()
xmlDoc.LoadXml(sourceString)

Dim node As XmlNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//api//query//search//p[1]")
If node IsNot Nothing Then
   If node.Attributes("titlesnippet") IsNot Nothing Then
      Dim titlesnippet As String = node.Attributes("titlesnippet").Value
      If InStr(titlesnippet, "searchmatch") > 0 Then
         WikiEN = node.Attributes("title").Value
      End If
   End If
End If
```

With this code the response Möhrenbach becomes MÃ¶hrenbach in VB.NET.

How can I save the right response?

Comment: What character encoding is your MySQL table using? I'm guessing it's not UTF8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the encoding for WebClient:

```
Dim webclient As System.Net.WebClient = New System.Net.WebClient()
webclient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8   '<---
```

With `webclient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8` everything comes over as should.

Comment: +1 for solving your own problem! I have already edited it out of your question and answer, but just for future reference, you should not use `<code>` tags on Stack Overflow. Just indenting the code with 4 spaces (like you did) is all you need to do. That will also ensure that you get code highlighting.

Comment: Thanks I will use your advice in the futer!